# PHP tries to Autoload Random Class Name

Tags: php, magento, autoload

A customer of mine is reporting an odd problem with some code in their Magento system (Magento is an ecommerce platform written in PHP).  I don't have direct access to the system to poke around and debug, so I thought I'd ask Stack Overflow if you've ever seen anything like this.

The error they're occasionally seeing is

```
Warning: include(O1ucm02owqn3iwwcx5osz2m2.php): failed to open stream:
```

With a call stack that includes

```
#0 /Users/theirusername/Sites/project/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(O1ucm02...', '/Users/theiruse...', 93, Array)
#1 /Users/theirusername/Sites/project/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('o1ucm02owqn3iww...')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('o1ucm02owqn3iww...')
#4 /Users/theirusername/Sites/project/app/code/local/Theirname/Commercebug/Model/Observer.php(191): defined('Mage_Core_Block...')
```

From this, I can deduce that PHP thinks it needs to instantiate a class named `O1ucm02owqn3iwwcx5osz2m2`.  However, I can't figure out **why** PHP might be doing this.  The lines that trigger the error (#4 in the callstack, around line 191 in `Observer.php`) should be

```
if(defined("Mage_Core_Block_Template::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS"))
{
    $path = Mage_Core_Block_Template::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS;
}
```

These lines don't seem to mention any PHP class named `O1ucm02owqn3iwwcx5osz2m2` (I say "should be" because the customer's deployed the code themselves, I'm working with them to get a copy to look for potential problems).

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?  Is this a a known PHP bug/issue with some version and/or has anyone seen an issues like this with PHP autoloaders/`defined`/class constants?

(I'm working with my customer to determine the version of PHP they're running, as well as getting a copy of the files they've deployed to ensure they match what I assume are there.)

Comment: What other 3rd party extensions are they using? Also what other PHP modules do they have? Feels like some type of corruption. Do they use APC or XCache or eAccelerator? Also, is it always the same class requested or is it always some string of random nonsense?

Comment: Happen to be using Zend Guard Loader by any chance? It seems that is overzealous in changing names from time to time and thus breaking scripts in the way you are describing

Comment: looks like malware to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defined() function serves as a compliment to the define() function for named constants. That is to say, constants declared with [define](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) can be nicely checked with [defined](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php).

However, that code is checking a [class constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), which while possible, is less typical. I suspect that the checking is triggering autoloading ([just as the use of class_exists can trigger autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).) However, the value handed off to the autoloader through use of defined is mangled (perhaps handing off the [hash of the z-val for the string](http://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/).)

I'm wondering if the following change would get things working:

```
// force PHP to load the class first, then let defined() check for the constant
if(class_exists("Mage_Core_Block_Template") && defined("Mage_Core_Block_Template::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS"))
{
    $path = Mage_Core_Block_Template::XML_PATH_DEBUG_TEMPLATE_HINTS;
}
```

As Alan noted in his comment, Zend Guard could be causing an issue, too.

Comment: +1 since almost everything you said is accurate and good advice, except for "usually the constants in a class don't change".  The checks that exist are there specifically because constants have been added to Magento over time, and my product needs to support previous versions that might not have those constants. (pretty sure it's a Zend Guard issue not playing nice with class constants in `defined`)

Comment: Valid points, Alan. I've updated the answer accordingly. The infrequent nature of these types of checks is what I wanted to highlight as a possible reason why a bug like this could sneak through, but, indeed, my language was initially too strong.